# how to get the passed value data from the database and show in a html table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have database and have table named **`supplier`**.it contains different columns like `region,country,9xx,10xx`.

I am fetching `9xx,10xx` columns in the drop down.When user select anyone of them,selected value will go to to the page where mysql query is performed and then result is shown in the html table.

The problem is i am not geting the records from the database for the passed values(i.e supplierid : 10xx or 9xx) ,please see my code

```
    <?php

    $dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
    $dbUsername = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    $dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $dbDatabase = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    $db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
    mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die("Could not select database.");

    $supplierid = $_GET['supplier_id'];
    //supplierid is 10xx or 9xx

    $sql = "SELECT region,country,$supplierid FROM supplierprice order by country ASC ";


   $sql_select = mysql_query($sql); 

    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql_select))
    {


    if($alt == 1)
            {
               echo '<tr class="alt">';
               $alt = 0;
            }
            else
            {
               echo '<tr>';
               $alt = 1;
            }

    echo '  

                <td id="CPH_GridView1_billingmonth " style="width:40px" class="edit billingmonth '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>   
                <td id="CPH_GridView1_country " style="width:101px" class="edit country '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>  

                <td id="CPH_GridView1_mnc " style="width:51px" class="edit mnc '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows[$supplierid].'</td> 

                </tr>';

    }

     ?>
```

Comment: `networkname,mcc,mnc,mnp,$supplier` should be `networkname,mcc,mnc,mnp,supplier` As in that part of the code you are selecting which columns you want returned.

Comment: $supplierid is 10xx or 9xx regarding user selected i wan t to return $supplierid

Comment: i tried $supplierid its print the coloumn name its not print the the values from the coloun

Comment: The column name is either 9xx or 10xx right? Which is stored in $supplierid? That is what your code is saying right now

Comment: yes the coloumn name is either 9xx or 10xx,if $supplierid is 10xx i want to display the values in the coloumn

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49118/discussion-between-arok-and-chitowns24)

Comment: Use $_REQUEST, insead of $_GET

Comment: You didn't selected `id` column in you SQL Query, but you are trying to use in `$row['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You are actually mixing HTML and PHP. They can be used together but not into each other, you should use the following code :

Just remove the following code :

```
echo '  

>                 <td id="CPH_GridView1_billingmonth " style="width:40px" class="edit billingmonth
> '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>   
>                 <td id="CPH_GridView1_country " style="width:101px" class="edit country '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>  
> 
>                 <td id="CPH_GridView1_mnc " style="width:51px" class="edit mnc '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows[$supplierid].'</td> 
> 
> 
>           </tr>';
> 
>     }
> 
>      ?>
```

and add the following CODE at its place

```
<td id="CPH_GridView1_billingmonth " style="width:40px" class="edit billingmonth '<?php.$rows["id"] ?>.'"> <?     php echo $row["region"]; ?> </td>                                                 
<td id="CPH_GridView1_billingmonth " style="width:40px" class="edit billingmonth '<?php.$rows["id"] ?>.'"> <? php echo $row["country"]; ?> </td>     
<td id="CPH_GridView1_billingmonth " style="width:40px" class="edit billingmonth '<?php.$rows["id"] ?>.'"> <?php echo $row["id"]; ?> </td>

    <?php

        }

         ?>
```

Hope this helps.